# How to map Object from http.get to Array?

Tags: json, typescript, kendo-ui, get, angular8

I have a service that fetches JSON data from local files.  I would like to convert the `Object` type that `http.get` returns to this array: `Array<{ bookName: string, bookId: number }>`.  You can see all of my source code in this [Github repository](https://github.com/xinthose/personal_website).

**[bible.service.ts](https://github.com/xinthose/personal_website/blob/master/src/app/bible.service.ts)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BibleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public fetch(file: string) {
    return this.http.get(file);
  }
}
```

**[bible.component.ts](https://github.com/xinthose/personal_website/blob/master/src/app/bible/bible.component.ts)** (simplified)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { BibleService } from "../bible.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bible',
  templateUrl: './bible.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bible.component.scss']
})
export class BibleComponent implements OnInit {
  dataBooks: Array<{ bookName: string, bookId: number }>;

  constructor(
    private bibleService: BibleService,
  ) {
    // fetch JSON data asynchronously 
    this.bibleService.fetch('./assets/bible/books.json')
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.dataBooks = response;  // how do I map this?
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      }, () => {
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The code is currently working with type `any`, but I would like to be more explicit with the data.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the overloads for the `httpClient.get()` method allows to specify the type that it returns:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BibleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public fetch(file: string) {
    return this.http.get<Array<{ bookName: string, bookId: number }>>(file); // <---------------
  }
}
```

Comment: OK.  Thank you sir.  I suppose I need a separate service method for each return then: books, chapters, and verses.

Comment: It looks like Overload #15 here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get